# How to update a variable outside a function in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How do I change the variable outside a function(in my case it is an eventListener)? I have a goal, which is a circle and I want its radius to change when the score is over 10. How do I update the variable to check what the radius is?

```
 local goal
 local goalRadius = 40

 local function checkScore()
   if(score>10)then
      goalRadius = 20
      --UPDATE THE VARIABLE?
 end


goal = display.newCircle(0,0,goalRadius)
goal:addEventListener("touch", checkScore)
```

Comment: You need an `end` to close the `if` but otherwise this should work (in plain Lua, I don't know about Corona). But it won't affect `goal`, which was created with a previous values of `goalRadius`. Perhaps you need to recreate `goal` inside `checkScore`.

Comment: If I recreate a goal in the eventListener what happens to the other goal? Does it just stay underneath? Does it get overwritten?

Comment: never mind, I figured it out, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to solve this proble was this: I used removeSelf() to delete the goal and then I recreated it.

```
 local goal
 local goalRadius = 40

 local function checkScore()
  if(score>10)then
       goal:removeSelf()
       goalRadius = 20
       goal = display.newCircle(0,0,goalRadius)
  end
 end


 goal = display.newCircle(0,0,goalRadius)
 goal:addEventListener("touch", checkScore)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need change radius of circle use `goal.width` and `goal.height`. Just remember that `goal.width == goal.height == two radii` for circle.